# How does Numpy sample random numbers from a non-uniform distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution, sampling

I have been learning about random sampling methods and am aware that Numpy uses Mersenne-Twister to generate uniform random numbers, how does it then pass these to generate non-uniform distributions?

For example:

```
np.random.normal(mu,sigma,n)
```

What algorithm is used here to sample normally distributed numbers? Thanks.

Comment: Possible relevant part of the (current) source code at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overall question is too broad, it could (and does) fill an [entire textbook](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/).

That said, a very quick overview is that techniques for generating **non-uniform random numbers** fall into a few common categories. These include:

1. Inverse transform of the cumulative distribution function (CDF);
2. Convolution (sums of random variables are themselves random
   variables with a different distribution);
3. Composition (decomposing a
   complex distribution into easier pieces using conditional
   probability);
4. Acceptance/rejection techniques (generate random "guesses", reject and
   retry if the constraints of the target distribution are violated); and
5. "Special Relationships" (recognizing that certain
   distributions have an intimate relationship with other distributions
   which are easier to generate).

A simple example of each of 1-3 & 5 can be found in Section 4.3 of [this tutorial paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf).

In practice, a combination of the techniques is often used.

For instance, the **normal distribution** cannot be found analytically by inversion because that would require being able to write a closed-form equation for the CDF.

[Two popular variants for generating normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) look at pairs of normals in polar coordinates, i.e., expressed as a direction and a distance. The basic Box-Muller algorithm notes that the direction is uniform from 0 to 2π, and Pythagoras tells us the distance is based on the sum of the squared normals, which has a chi-square(2) distribution (convolution). "Special relations" tell us that a chi-square(2) is an exponential(2), which is easy to generate via inversion. Pulling all the pieces together and converting back to Cartesian coordinates gives the pair of formulas found in the Wikipedia article.

The second variant is [Marsaglia's Polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method), which appears to be the [method used by NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L601). It avoids the evaluation of sine/cosine transcendental functions by generating points randomly in a square, and rejecting any that aren't contained within a circumscribed circle (acceptance/rejection). It then scales the results using the same chi-square/exponential distance calculation, so it's also drawing on convolution, "special relationships, " and inversion.

The fastest approaches are based on the [ziggurat algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm), which breaks the normal into layers (composition), uses special relations for some of the layers, and uses acceptance/rejection to deal with the tails of a layer.

Comment: The question is not necessarily what algorithms _exist_ to generate normal random numbers, but rather what algorithm _NumPy uses_  to generate such numbers.  While NumPy's algorithm for `numpy.random.normal` hasn't changed for years due to backward compatibility, that might not be the case in the future (see the new [Numpy RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst)).

Comment: @PeterO. The point is that NumPy has to use one or more of the fundamental techniques, and in the case of normals it uses Marsaglia's Polar method (as stated in the answer).  The question specifically asked "...how does it then pass these to generate non-uniform distributions?" followed by the normal as a "for example."  I interpreted that as wanting to know the techniques that are involved.  If not, there is no single answer that covers the entire suite of RV generation provided by NumPy and your best bet is to look at the sources for all of them.  That's way too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Re-reading the question I see that it applies to all "non-uniform distributions" supported by NumPy, not just the normal distribution.  In that case, the NumPy source code is the best way to document them all.